# What's the meaning of the term" dynamical behavior" of solutions of some PDEs (maybe an evolution equations)?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

What's the meaning of the term" dynamical behavior" of solutions of some PDEs (maybe an evolution equations)? This term often appears in the papers I read.